# Using a mirrored curve as bevel object

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, mirror-modifier

I need to use a symmetrical curve as bevel object following another curve.
Both are bezier originally, but when assigned as bevel object, the mirror (with merge checked) is ignored and only the original curve is used.

Converting the curve to mesh only makes the curve unusable for beveling.

If possible, I need to keep it editable to adjust the final shape.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/569155dcefa041e588ea18f6660e2681

Comment: I'm not sure the modifier will be taken into account when you'll choose the curve as profile. Maybe convert to mesh then reconvert to curve?

Comment: Well, doing as you say, the curve is applied correctly, but it's not easly editable anymore. I also tried to simplify but result is not nice. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to mirror a curve actually  ;((